# Upload blob to azure

Tags: visual-studio-2012, azure, azure-blob-storage, server-explorer

I've connected the server explorer in VS 2012 to my public blob container.

In VS 2010 there is a button for uploading files, but there doesn't seem to be one in VS 2012.

Am I blind, or is the functionality actually missing?

While I'm at it, does anybody know the difference between "Public container" and "Public blob", under container settings in the azure portal? I have my container set as "Public blob".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Public Container means anonymous/unauthenticated requests can list the blobs in the container as well as access the blobs in that container.  Public blob means anyone can access blobs in that container given a URL to a given blob but they cannot list the blobs within that container.  (See [Set Container ACL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dd179391.aspx) documentation)

As for the upload button, I'm not seeing one in VS2010 or VS2012, but [MSDN doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ff683677.aspx) does refer to its existence.  I've always used third party tools like Cloudberry Explorer or Cerebrata CloudStorage Studio.

Comment: Thanks! I was totally baffled, upon reading about the button's existence, but not being able to find it. Cloudberry Explorer to the rescue :).

Answer (score 5):

we finally added full read/write support for Blobs and Queues in the latest release of the Azure SDK for .NET / Visual Studio Azure tools (October 2012).  This lets you do a number of things that are helpful for building an app using storage like upload a blob, batch upload, batch download, delete, create containers, set public container access, enqueue/dequeue, etc.  Neither VS 2010 or VS 2012 have Azure tools installed by default which makes me think you may have a previous version of the SDK.  Please go ahead and [install the latest SDK](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/?slideshow=5) (can be done side by side with your existing version, and it's free) and you should be golden.

Btw, the steps to upload are open your bob container via double click, at the top of the containers window you see a filter by preview text box and several icons.  Look for the "up arrow" icon.  It sits between the refresh icon and the x icon, third to the right of the filter box.

Let me know if you have questions.  I'm happy to upload a screenshot if that helps.

Paul Yuknewicz, Microsoft Visual Studio

Comment: Thank you! That little "up arrow" icon was really hard to find.

Answer (score 2):

Just to add to Paul's comment above - In [Azure SDK for .NET 2.0](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/#) (released on April 30, 2013), we've added functionality to upload and delete table entities. In addition, we've added a Query Builder to make it easier to search for specific entities. Hope you enjoy the goodies.

[MSDN documentation on Azure storage tools in Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ff683677.aspx)

Merwan Hade, Microsoft Visual Studio